# Rmarkdown Euro symbol correctly shown in main text, but not in R output

Tags: r, character-encoding, r-markdown

I am using R markdown to write a report. Given that the report uses income data I sometimes use the € symbol. This is not a problem when the symbol occurs in the main text, but it does cause trouble whenever the R code generates output that contains the symbol (for example in reference to a level label that contains the symbol)

If I render the document to HTML or Word, the symbol simply doesn't show up. If I try to render the document to PDF it just gives me an error.

I suspect it is driven by the fact that the encoding-set used for R output is different from the one used for the rest of the document but I have no idea how to change that.

Minimal reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Example"
output:
  html_document: default

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

No trouble with € in main text

```{r}

#But this causes trouble, although only in the output. The code itself is reproduced fine.
print('€')

```
````

Session info:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] backports_1.1.0 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.3.2     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.9     stringi_1.1.2   rmarkdown_1.6  
[10] knitr_1.16      stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Comment: Open the HTML document in the browser, right click on the output of that chunk and select "Insepct Element". What do you see? There should be a `<code>## [1] "€"</code>`. I cannot reproduce this problem myself. This might be a problem connected to your locale.

Comment: @Martin-Schmelzer It says: ## [1] "", that is there is a little square containing numbers 0080 (I don't think they actually show up if I copy paste them in this comment). I hope it's not a problem connected to my locale. I can work my way around it of course but it's annoying.

Comment: Thats the unicode version of the euro symbol (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm). Hmmm let me think.

Comment: Quite challenging. I've tried downloading https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/eurosym/sty?lang=en (eurosym.sty) to .Rmd directory and used either header-includes:
   - \usepackage{eurosym} but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

With \text and euro unicode should be solved:

```
$\text{€}$
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).